# How do I create a moving animations when going to another page with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

so I got my site up and running but I wanted to add a sort of moving animation when going to another page or some loading animation thing, so it does'nt look like that its refreshing the page.

I only know HTML and some CSS, nothing else but planning to learn JS and PHP.
Thanks!

(Im using Bootstrap with a theme called Paper which makes it looks like material design, its from bootswatch.com)

Comment: it's a too broad question... You should try something yourself and come here to ask specific questions after using your own effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldnt say this is a broad question, but i would say it needs a js fiddle or something example of the code..

Problem is websites are built in 101 ways, so even if someone supplies you code.. Without the knowledge of javascript, you would still most likely need someone to modify it to suite your site or would have a few questions along the way.

As for javascript, to make your life easy... start with a libary like jQuery... This will save you time and effort for now..

As for the process.. Well it can vary...
Say you have a standard page and it has a DIV element which has all your content except for the header/menu/footer.

What you would do is...

1. POST request to your PHP web server to get a copy of the requested page (this would be just the content.. no header/menu/footer)
2. Hide/fade/move your current DIV element which has the current page contents
3. Once its been moved/changed.. you would replace the HTML with the HTML you 
   received from the POST
4. Show/fade/move the DIV element back to where it started....
5. your done... sounds easy, but varies..

   ```
   function loadPage(sPage) {
       $(".site-heading > h1").html("Loading");
       $(".site-heading > span").html("Please wait while we fetch your page");

       $("#pageContents").fadeTo(200, 0.5);
       $(".intro-header").fadeTo(200, 0.5, function(){
           $.post("index.php", { ajax: "page", page:sPage }).done(function( data ) {
               var oJSON = $.parseJSON(data);
               if (typeof oJSON.success != 'undefined') {
                   if (oJSON.success==true) {
                       $(".intro-header").css({"background-image":"url('images/" + sPage + "-bg.jpg')"});
                       $("#pageContents").html(oJSON.page);
                       $(".site-heading > h1").html(oJSON.header_text);
                       $(".site-heading > span").html(oJSON.header_subtext);
                       $(".intro-header").fadeTo(200, 1);
                       $("#pageContents").fadeTo(200, 1);
                   }
               }
               //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
           });         
       });     
   }
   ```

The above is a JS function from some old code which does the above..

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ajax']) && $_REQUEST['ajax']=="page" && isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    $sPage = "engine/pages/" . $_REQUEST['page'] . "/index.php";
    $oRet = array();
    $oRet['success'] = false;
    $oRet['page'] = false;

    if (file_exists($sPage)) {
        $sPageSettings = "engine/pages/" . $_REQUEST['page'] . "/settings.php";
        if (file_exists($sPageSettings)) {
            require $sPageSettings;
        }

        $oRet['success'] = true;
        $oRet['page'] = file_get_contents($sPage);
        $oRet['header_text'] = $oPage['header_text'];
        $oRet['header_subtext'] = $oPage['header_subtext'];
    }
    echo json_encode($oRet);
    exit;
}
```

Is the PHP code that responds to the request and sends the HTML back to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are asking about dynamic page loading .
so that is achived by using ajax.
with this u can display multiple pages without refreshing 
and u can also ADD animation of your own to show some loading effect 
these are the links using this effect ..

http://www.reverbnation.com/

http://clicklinks.be/tutorials/javascript/prototype/page-loading/demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this would be really hard to accomplish with only HTML and CSS. You need to know at least JS. You can do it with AJAX, by calling the second page's content and loading it in the current page, or if you're not comfortable with AJAX, you can do a simple hack with javascript. You can disable the link to the second page, and when clicked on second page link, you could animate the first page leaving. Then, on page load (2nd page), you can do the enter animation. If you can provide a jsfiddle, it will be easier for us to help.